# error in postgres (connection limit exceeded for non-superusers)

Tags: postgresql

We got an error from postgres one day.
"connection limit exceeded for non-superusers"

In postgresql.conf setting, the max_connection is 100.
At that time I checked the access with command (select * from   pg_stat_activity;)
the result only 17 access.

We used this application for almost 10 years and never done any changed.
This is the first time we received this kind of error.
So, I assume that "not closing the connections properly in program " 
is not the cause of this error.

Any tips?

Comment: PostgreSQL version? Other details? At a guess, I'd say you had a burst of connections that was gone by the time you went and checked.

Comment: I'm also inclined to believe Postgres more in this case then you - if Postgres says the connections are used, then they are. Craig is probably right: the problem was gone at the time you checked `pg_stat_activity` Another possibility: your session that checked `pg_stat_activity` had an open transaction - in that case `pg_stat_activity` shows the state when your transaction began.